# How best to read out a whole array into a scope with Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am working on an Ionic project. And I have this url with json data, basically the json data is build up like this:

[image]

What I am trying to accomplish is a playlist of all these videos from youtube.

I have created a service where I make an http request with the url (which works perfect:

```
angular.module('Chemicar.services', [])

.service('ChemicarService', function($http, $q){

    var url_youtube = "XXXXX";
    var youtubeId;

    var self = {
        'youtubeVideos' : [],
        'youtubeVideoId' : [],
        'loadYoutubeVideos' : function(){
            var d =  $q.defer();
            $http.get(url_youtube)
            .success(function(data){
                //console.log(data);
                self.youtubeVideos = data
                //console.log(self.youtubeVideos);

                for(var i = 0; i < self.youtubeVideos.length; i++){
                    //console.log(self.youtubeVideos[i].video);
                    youtubeId = self.youtubeVideos[i].video;
                    //console.log("Youtube video id: ", youtubeId);
                    self.youtubeVideoId = youtubeId;
                    console.log("Youtube video id: ", self.youtubeVideoId);
                }
                d.resolve(data);
            })
            .error(function(msg){
                console.error("There was an error in retrieving the json data " , msg);
                d.reject("The promise was not fulfilled");
            });
            return d.promise;
        }
    };
    return self;
});
```

And the code for my controller is the following:

```
angular.module('Chemicar.controllers', ['Chemicar.services'])

.controller('VideoCtrl', function($scope, $http, ChemicarService){

    $scope.youtubeVideos = [];

    ChemicarService.loadYoutubeVideos().then(function success (data){
        $scope.youtubeVideos = ChemicarService.youtubeVideos;
        $scope.youtubeVidId = ChemicarService.youtubeVideoId;
        $scope.youtubeUrl = 'http:///www.youtube.com/embed/'+$scope.youtubeVidId; 
        console.log('Youtube Video URL', $scope.youtubeUrl);

    })

})
```

As you can see from my console (last line - controller side), it will only read out the last youtube video in the array. What I need is that it reads out the whole array. How best to achieve this.

[image]

Comment: there seem to be multiple issues with this code, but the most obvious is that you create an array and then continually replace the array with a single value.  instead of `self.youtubeVideoId = youtubeId;`, try `self.youtubeVideoId.push(youtubeId)`.  Though it's not really obvious why you want to push duplicate data into the second array in the first place....

Comment: also, if you are storing the values in an array in the service, then that won't work too well with the `$scope.youtubeUrl = 'http:///www.youtube.com/embed/'+$scope.youtubeVidId` line, which expects a single value....

Comment: @Claies, i thought this would be the best way to go about creating a playlist with ng-repeat ...

Comment: @Claies, ok what is the best approach then that i should take?

Comment: again, I'm not really clear on why you are receiving an array, then iterating through that array and trying to push those values into another array, creating a duplicate of the original data.  why not just use the value from the first array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GY22,

There are multiple issues here, but I would remove the for loop from the service and pass the array to the controller. There is no sense in having both `youtubeVideos` and `loadYoutubeVideos` arrays.

In your case you can eliminate the use of `q`, you can simply Return the promise like this:

```
var self = {
    'loadYoutubeVideos' : function(){
        return $http.get(url_youtube);
    }
};

return self;
```

Then inside of your controller, to avoid interpolation error. You will need to inject [`$sce` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) into your controller and use the `trustAsResourceUrl` method when setting your `urls`. You will have:

```
angular.module('Chemicar.controllers', ['Chemicar.services'])

.controller('VideoCtrl', function($scope, $http, ChemicarService,$sce){

    $scope.items= [];

    ChemicarService.loadYoutubeVideos()
    .then(function(response){
         $scope.items = response.data;
         angular.forEach($scope.items, function(item) {
          item.youtubeUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('http:///www.youtube.com/embed/' + item.video);
        });
    });
})
```

Then in your html, you can do something of the sort:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <iframe ng-src="{{item.youtubeUrl}}></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: i followed along with your code but in doing so i had to change my controller to match yours. so now when i want to readout all the videos like so:  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
                <iframe src="http:///www.youtube.com/embed/{{ item.video }}" frameborder="0" width="550" height="315"></iframe>
            </div>  . i get the error in my console say this -> https://gyazo.com/05f2a85805d2ac3fbb86938c6c11359f

Comment: i update the code with your suggestion, but still getting an error -> https://gyazo.com/8619670e391e8f18b569576f2f030761 . i will google it and see how to solve this interpolation error

Comment: ok so far so good is guess. i don't have any errors in my console.log but for some reason there are no videos showing up in my view -> https://gyazo.com/f30e5e41706497c27dc16062a22d26cd

Comment: made the change but view is still not showing any videos and also no errors in the console ... (this is a difficult one)

Comment: https://gyazo.com/c19c9304504daae69e564d0bf35b15ed. i must say now cause we changed the controller you can see that youtubeUrl is now TrustedValueHolderType, where as before is was the actual youtube url with the id already in it

Comment: Yes i just so that mistake i left but still same result after updating the iframe

Comment: not sure what you mean or how to do this with chrome developer tool

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94741/discussion-between-inspired-and-gy22).